# Find correct path via case intensive pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am am trying to convert incorrect case insensitive paths into their correct case sensitive ones.

Given a path like `./cAsE/SeNsItIvE` how can I find the proper path with this form? `./CaSe/sEnSiTiVe`?

Example isn't mean to imply I am looking for complete inversion -- i.e `.\DIR\file` should resolve to `./dir/file` if `./dir/file` is that which exists in the system.

I have been playing with glob, obviously, and can't find a rule to handle this.

I won't bore anyone with my lackluster efforts.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I ended up building a database of all valid paths and then matching the paths being fed in with a case insensitive pattern.

Interested if there is a better way to do this:

```
#build path database to resolve mispelled paths
paths = []
def build_path_db():
    global paths
    for filename in iglob('/mdt/**', recursive=True):
        abs_path = Path(filename).resolve() # get the absolute path
        rel_path = abs_path.relative_to('/mdt') # convert to relative path    
        paths.append(rel_path)
build_path_db()

#takes string, returns string
def unixify_path(win_path):
    pure_win_path = PureWindowsPath(win_path)
    #print(pure_win_path)
    posix_path = Path(pure_win_path)

    #check if path is valid
    if posix_path.exists():
        print('already correct!')
    else:
        #print('incorrect!')
        posix_path_str = str(posix_path)

        #computer case insensitive regex pattern for hunted file
        pattern = compile(translate(posix_path_str), IGNORECASE)

        #check to see if case inensitive pattern matches actual paths
        for path in paths:
            if pattern.match(str(path)):
                #print('match found! %s ' % path)
                return path
```

Comment: "I won't bore anyone with my lackluster efforts." - I think it's better if you provide your attempts anyway, it will improve your question and make helping easer.

Comment: Also, do you just want a case insensitive match (i.e. Windows machine), or closes match? On Linux, if both `a/b/c` and `A/B/c` exist, would you match both?

Comment: You can compare the two paths as lower case and if they match then you know the rest.

Comment: I want to emulate Windows path resolution on *nix machine.


I have Windows paths on a *nix machine that don't work because the case is wrong.

I want to turn that incorrect path into a working one on the *nix machine.

I don't have to worry about collisions.